# ruby / savon web service relative URL

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, wsdl, savon

I tried to use savon to write a client call tweb service.
This is wsdl:

```
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="ExecuteCableEdgeCSR">
<soap:operation soapAction="CableEdge/CSR/ExecuteRequest"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="CableEdgeCSRService">
<port name="CSRPort" binding="this:CSRSoapBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost/service/soap/message"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

and my ruby code:

```
    require 'savon'
    @client = Savon::Client.new(
    wsdl: "http://192.168.3.165/schema?wsdl",
    endpoint: "http://192.168.3.165/schema",
    namespace: "http://www.c-cor.com/ns/ce-ws/1.0.0",
    basic_auth: ["...", "..."],
    )
    puts @client.operations 
    # Get result is OK, client can get the right operations list 
    # "execute_cable_edge_csr"
    @response = @client.call(:execute_cable_edge_csr, xml: requst_xml) 
    # test request_xml is long and ommited here...
```

WSDL address is 192.168.3.165/schema?wsdl and can be access by browser, and client can get the correct operaions list (ony one operation...)
The problem is: @response cannot not the result what :execute_cable_edge_csr should return, but the standard description of the web service.

I've found some clue: 
The document of the service include:

> The WSC is accessible to remote clients via either SOAP or XML over
>   HTTP.  SOAP using document/literal encoding:  The URL for this
>   service is /service/soap/message  XML over HTTP:    The URL for
>   this service is /service/xml. The HTTP POST command should
>   associate "xml_request" name to the value part  which contains the XML
>   content.

And It provide a browser-test page, which call the web service by JavaScript:

```
    function submitSoap(){
    ...
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/service/soap/message",true);
    ...
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("MessageType", "CALL")
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "CableEdge/CSR/ExecuteRequest")
    ...
    xmlhttp.send(request);
    }
```

This script send the request xml in the textarea of the page to sever and works fine, response right result.

I used WiresShark catch the content which send to the server to compare the with same xml body. The MAIN difference is the frist line.
MY RUBY SAVON PROGRAM:
POST /schema HTTP/1.1

...
and EXAMPLE JAVASCRIPT PROGRAM:
POST /service/soap/message HTTP/1.1
..

I think the key is where to include the relative url  **/service/soap/message** in my savon client. I tried to change endpoint: "192.168.3.165/schema" to endpoint: **192.168.3.165/service/soap/message**, but it doesn't works(ruby returns error).

Could any one can tell the right way?